# How to handle two or more domainevents in c#?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, domain-events

In C# I have a scenario where in at least 2 places different domain events are raised and I want a single hander to handle them with the same code (other listeners may perform the event specific code).
With the handlers using the following pattern;

```
public class SomeHandler : IHandler<SomeEvent>
{
   public SomeHandler()
   {
      //whatever init code
   }

   public void Handle(SomeArgs args)
   {
       //Common code
   }
}
```

So what is the best way to handle more than one Event with the same Handler?
Thanks

Comment: Silly decision, keep things simple. I've never seen such thing as a handler handling different types of event. (beside using properties of an event base class if it has one)

Comment: This isn't really DDD .. its more EDA - perhaps re-tagging is required?

Comment: The reasoning is that there is common code to perform in both events and I don't want to duplicate it (DRY).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IHandler<SomeEvent>` is an interface so perhaps you can implement multiple ones:

```
public class SomeHandler : IHandler<SomeEvent>, IHandler<SomeOtherEvent>
{
   public SomeHandler()
   {
      //whatever init code
   }

   public void Handle(SomeArgs args)
   {
       //Common code
   }

   public void Handle(SomeOtherArgs args)
   {
       //Common code
   }
}
```

Comment: This solves it - thanks. (I'll consider whether I've got some higher design decisions prompted by Aybe).